# Newline character '\n' (return key) in *nix!

Tags: bash, newlines

While studying Linux, I noticed that the newline character is used not only to separate different lines - that is to set the beginning and the end of a line - but also is used to give some input to the shell.

For example, while logging in, the system asks for a username and password. When I type those information, then the system expects me to type `\n` to provide the typed information. This happens also when I type a command on the bash. Can someone explain me why it is used `\n` for such cases?

I guess `\n` is used both for start a new line (indeed the cursor goes down when I press enter) but also to provide an input to the system (it is like a "send" button on a web page). Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a graphical interface you can use the mouse to select the field for text entry. There's usually a button that you can also click - with the mouse - to submit the information.

However, what is much less well known is that it's possible to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> (and <kbd>Shift tab</kbd>) to move between fields, and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> itself to submit the data you've entered. (The cursor keys move around the data within an individual field, but do not move between fields themselves.)

This second approach maps more closely onto the non-graphical way of entering information, where you (almost) always have to use the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to submit a line of data into the system. The system is fundamentally line-oriented, hence the name "command line interpreter", or CLI. (In some instances you can use the cursor keys to move left/right along the current line of data, but using the up/down keys won't necessarily do what you might initially expect.)

This is normal.